# Importing the colored value from a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with two separate sheets. I need to import the colored value from a range of sheet to the column C of Sheet 2. In short, something like,

> If Sheet1!A4=Sheet2!A3, Sheet2!C3=The colored value of the range
>   Sheet1!(C7:AG7)

and

> If Sheet1!A10=Sheet2!A4, Sheet2!C4=The colored value of the range
>   Sheet1!(C13:AG13)

[Here is a test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bxht4jWM-qchQjALEYQW3SK3gWipkfj0rcSiWarPKcc/edit#gid=135649841)

Any idea?

Comment: do you mean to say get the values from the colored range? What have you tried?

Comment: Not actually the colored range. Rather the value which is colored in a range. And I couldn't apply any idea to solve the problem.